# C++ UI framework from scratch?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I want to create a C++ UI framework (something like QT or like ubuntu unity Desktop)

How is programmed , is it using OpenGL or lets take plasma ui of QT (how is this programmed )?

Direct answers , reference links anything will be helpful.

Some interesting opengl based UI I founf on the web

### LiquidEngine

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0saaAIjIEY

### Libnui

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libnui

Comment: you can download the source and find out :)

Comment: To develop a UI framework from scratch, you must first create the universe.

Answer (score 3):

Some UI frameworks render everything themselves, and work based on some kind of clipping-window-within-the-host-systems-screen. Non-display aspects (such as input event handling) have to be translated to/from the host systems underlying APIs.

Some UI frameworks translate as much as possible to some underlying framework.

wxWidgets can do both. You can choose a native version (e.g. wxMSW if you're on Windows) and most wxWidgets controls will be implemented using native Windows controls. Equally, you can choose the wxUniversal version, where all controls are implemented by the wxWidgets library itself.

The trouble is that typical GUI frameworks are huge. If you want a more manageable example to imitate, you might look at FLTK. I haven't got around to studying it myself, but it has a reputation for being consise.

There are also some GUI toolkits that are specifically aimed at games programming, such as Crazy Eddies GUI. My guess - these are probably as idependent of the underlying API as possible, so that particular applications can implement the mapping to whichever underlying API they happen to target (OpenGL, DirectX, SDL, whatever) and can be the boss of the GUI rather than visa versa.

- http://www.wxwidgets.org/
- http://www.fltk.org/
- http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: FWIW, Stroustrup uses FLTK in his book "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++".

Answer (score 1):

> **"no really, don't write your own wm or toolkit"**
>
> *The #Xorg-devel guys on irc.freenode.org*

doing one anyway means that you have to test against a wide range of more or less buggy WMs and X implementations, and that you have to frequently update to be compatible with the latest Xorg server and X protocol features (like Xinput 2.1)

understandably, the Xorg people are tired to support old, unmaintained toolkits and applications. They already have enough bugs.

Comment: But writing a toolkit isn't the same as releasing a toolkit. He may just want to do a learning exercise kind of thing, seeing how the internals of a simple GUI toolkit work.

Comment: Thanks Steve , thatz exactly what I wanted to do . But if can get things right , I am going to use for my own venture ...

Answer (score 0):

The GUI frameworks are very dependant on a windows system, which dictates what is allowed and how windows are created and rendered. For example, pass a specific option to create a borderless or full-screen window.

Since you mentioned opengl and ubuntu, I guess you want to start on a linux platform. You should study xlib, for which you can find reference [here](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_ACRO_SUP/XWINSYS.PDF).

Since the qt library is open source, you can download it and peek into it's sources.

Comment: Some interesting opengl based UI I founf on the web

LiquidEngine
-------------
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0saaAIjIEY

Libnui
------
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libnui

Answer (score -3):

A UI library *isn't* developed from scratch. It relies on the OS' windowing system, which relies on the driver from your graphics adapter, which relies on the OS kernel, which relies on... and so on.

To develop any software "from scratch", you can start by writing your own BIOS. Once you're done with that, move on to writing an OS, and then you should be just about ready to write the software you wanted. Good luck.

And this is assuming you're willing to cheat, of course, and use a compiler you *didn't* write from scratch.

Comment: I think the GTK team would be irritated to be told they didn't develop a UI library from scratch - though of course X does underly GTK.

Comment: Exactly. As does the Windows windowing system. And neither of those are developed "from scratch" either. They are based on other layers of the OS, and eventually, it's all layered on top of the low-level drivers and firmware that makes your graphics card put pixels on the screen.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid, and this answer is retarded. The OP already states that from scratch should be interpreted relative to OpenGL and C++ as a starting point. I'm not sure why you are taking 'from scratch' so literally. Obviously the OP wanted to know on what frameworks/libraries/concepts a typical GUI like Qt is build on, he even explicitly mentioned this.

Answer (score -3):

Before you do that, it's worth that you spend one week on thinking:
1, Do you really know how to do it? I doubt that.
2, Do you really need to do it? I doubt that too.

Comment: That's a typical of `Let's Never Move Forward!` paradigm.

Comment: Usually you do this either to only learn from it (either to understand current solutions, or to learn the required programming language/libraries), or because you want to have a very minimalist UI framework that is specific to your application.